# How to determine if outcome of two detection methods on same set of sample was due to chance?

Tags: chi-squared-test, independence

I am comparing two methods to detect a virus in 2,337 tumors. Method A found virus V in 1472 tumors (63.0% of tumors). Method B found virus V in a much lower number of tumors, n=17 (0.73%). A contingency table shows that method A and B find virus V in an intersection of 11 tumors. Here is the 2 way table:

```
       B  no   yes
A   no    859  6
    yes   1461 11
```

What statistical test do I need to use to determine if this result was just random?

Answer (score 2):

I still stand with my first answer, that Fisher's test is right to demonstrate, that there is no proof of any relation between both tests. In a comment, the original poster put the question a little bit different as

> What I want to know is this: what is the chance that given a Yes rate of Method A and B at 63% and 0.73%, respectively, what is the random chance that there would be an overlap of 11 "Yes" samples?

That could be tested via the binomial distribution. I testA-positive and testB-positive are independent, than the chance of hitting both by chance is $0.63\times 0.0073 = 0.004599$ the chance of this happening 11 times in 2337 you can look up. Less precise but maybe more convincing: You can do a computer simulation very easily:

```
replicate(10000, expr = {
    testA <- sample(c("pos", "neg"), size = 2337, prob = c(.63, 1-.63), replace = TRUE)
    testB <- sample(c("pos", "neg"), size = 2337, prob = c(.0073, 1-.0073), replace = TRUE)
    return(sum(testA=="pos" & testA==testB))
    })
```

This will draw a sample of the size 2337 with the given probability for testA and another for testB and result how often both are positive. This is then repeated 10000 times. The counts of each possible result can then easily be printed: 
[image]

Larger numbers of replications will make this more precise, but the result is consistent with Fisher's test: You can by far not reject the null hypothesis, that both tests react independend from the other.

Answer (score 1):

The contingency table you prepared would document whether the probability that test B finds a positive result differs depending on whether test A finds a positive result, which does not seem to be your main interest.

If your question is whether the A and B tests give positive results in different proportions of cases, then you need to do a test on the proportions. In R, the `prop.test()`function is one simple solution. According to the help page, the matrix you need to prepare has A and B as rows, with the first column the number of successes and the second column the number of failures for each test.

For your data, with 2337 tumors, A finding 1472 positive and B finding 17 positive, you have a highly significant result:

```
> dataTable <- matrix(c(1472,17,2337-1472,2337-17),nrow=2)
> dataTable
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 1472  865
[2,]   17 2320

> prop.test(dataTable)

2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction

data:  dataTable
X-squared = 2083.595, df = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
0.6022884 0.6428977
sample estimates:
     prop 1      prop 2 
0.629867351 0.007274283
```

Comment: I'm not interested in if the proportions are significantly different. I know that Method A has a more loose definition of detection and so will have a higher proportion labelled as "yes". Method B is much stricter in how it defines if a virus is present. What I want to know is this: what is the chance that given a Yes rate of Method A and B at 63% and 0.73%, respectively, what is the random chance that there would be an overlap of 11 "Yes" samples?

Answer (score 0):

Your odd's ratio is very close to 1 even though you have large numbers. So there is no effect. In R you can ask the function `fisher.test` for a 95% confidence intervall of the odds ratio:

```
> tab <- matrix(c(859,1451,6,11), nrow=2)
> fisher.test(tab)

         Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  tab
p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.3663544 3.5874569
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
  1.085316
```

As you can see, OR == 1 is within the confidence intervall and the Fisher tests returns a p-value of 1, so both appear to be independent. Being positive in one test does not neccessarily influence, whether a tumor will be positive in the other test as well. However, with the small number of positives in B, these numbers are not very reliable, thus the large confidence intervall (could be an OR == 3...)

Comment: This test just shows that there is no difference in the probability of B finding a positive result based on whether A found a positive result. It does not answer the OP about whether A and B find virus in a different proportion of cases. That would require, say, a test of the binomial proportions.

Comment: @EdM Just because you have a different interpretation of what the OP probably wants is no reason to down vote my answer. Hopefully the OP will disclosure who got it right.